# Counting and grouping similar strings in a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a database table, `users`, with a lot of names and genders in it, and I need to find the most common first name for either gender?

```
|      name      |   sex  |
----------------------------
|     Foo Bar    |  male  |
|     Foo Boq    |  male  |
|     Plo Boa    |  male  |
|     Loo Baa    | female |
|     Boo Faa    | female |
|     Boo Sar    | female |
```

The best I can come up with is something along the lines of (for e.g. males)

```
SELECT  name, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    users WHERE sex='male'
GROUP   BY name
ORDER   BY totalCount DESC
LIMIT   1
```

The result I was hoping for was

```
Foo
```

After which I realized that doesn't take last names into account. There's too much data in this table for me to try and separate the data (unless there's relatively easy way I can do that?)

Would it be possible to use REGEX or some permutation of `'$name%'` (Running the query with PHP!)

Thanks! :-)

Comment: How are you differentiating the first name and last name by a space between name column ?

Comment: The first name and last name are separated by a space, both contained within the 'name' column, e.g. "Foo Bar" - Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1)` in `GROUP BY`,As first name and last name are separated by space in name column also confirmed by op in comments

```
SELECT  name, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    table1
WHERE sex='male'
GROUP   BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1)
ORDER   BY totalCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79690f/4)

Comment: Do you know if using a substring_index would affect performance on the query?  OP said that there is a lot of data in the table.

Comment: Thanks @MKhalidJunaid! Works great :-) @Jack, Definitely a noticeable performance drop, but it's not too bad. Was very confused at first, forgot I needed to explode the output! (Shows both first and last name when echoed, heh) Cheers!